# What kind of power supply filter is this?

Tags: power-supply, diodes, filter, coil

I found this filter in an inherited design. It is supposed to filter some noisy input (around 13V) coming from a generator.

I'm new to designing filters and coils but something feels off here - I kind of expected a resistor for a low-pass. Is this some kind of standard filter against voltage spikes? I did not find any documentation for this.

The reason I'm asking is that recently I got a board back where D1 was burnt and I'm looking for ways to improve this.

[image: filter]

Comment: Where is the output node? Where is the input node? What is the supply noise it is trying to filter? What generates the supply? Provide datasheet links to both components please.

Comment: D1 is a TVS, I guess you could almost call it a low pass filter if you were trying to bend terms to fit. It's to protect against transients rather than for filtering though.

Comment: @Colin Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D1 in that circuit is a [Transient Voltage Suppressor](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/tvs-diodes/surface-mount/p6smb/p6smb16ca.aspx), this is designed to protect other devices attached between `VCC` and `GND` from short term over voltage events. It doesn't really provide any filtering from noise though.

If it burned that suggests it was subjected to a longer lasting period of over voltage than it was able to handle.

Comment: Can you describe the role of the inductor?

Comment: It seems a bit odd to me @Reinderien, it’d be good to see the rest of the circuit

Comment: From the symbol, I guess it is unidirectional TVS diode.